# using taylor series to prove $\lim_{{x}\to+{\infty}}e^{-x}=0$ equal to zero without using its algebraic fact.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

To be more specific. We know $e^{-x}$=$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}{x^k}$, without using the fact that $e^{-x}$=$\frac{1}{e^x}$ and using taylor expansion on $e^x$, how do we prove $\lim_{{x}\to+{\infty}}e^{-x}=0$ just through manipulation of taylor series of $e^{-x}$?

Comment: Taylor series have meaning ( of convergence) when seen around a neighbourhood of a point. How can you do this as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Why not just prove that $e^{-x} = 1/e^x$ from the Taylor series, then proceed from there?

Comment: we can just expand it around x = 0, since its radius of convergency is $\infty$. There may be involved with some manipulation that changes the point where we expand it, I'm not sure. But it is doable.

Comment: Prof left it to let us think about...He tends to let us "enjoy" the process of dealing with the manipulation of taylor expansion. And we need to prove they are exactly the same when we expand it around different points in which case they may look completely different.

Comment: Are you allowed to do a substitution on the e-power to convert it into an ln, or does that fall under using its algebraic fact?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what your professor wanted, but here is one approach that
relies on properties of differential equations, specifically uniqueness.

Let $x(t) = e^{-t}$, note that $\dot{x} = - x$. We note that $t \mapsto 0$ is a solution (with initial condition 0), and $x(0) = 1$, so we have $x(t) > 0$ for all $t \ge 0$ (this is where uniqueness is used). Hence $x$ is strictly decreasing and bounded below, hence
$x_\infty = \lim_{t \to \infty} x(t)$ exists and is non negative.

If $x_\infty >0$, then we have $x(t) \ge x_\infty$ and so
$\dot{x}(t) \le -x_\infty$ which would give $x(t) \le 1 - t x_\infty$ and
contradict non negativity, hence $x_\infty = 0$.

**Alternative**:

Compute the Taylor series of the function $\phi(x) = e^x e^{-x}$. Note that the Taylor series is $x \mapsto 1$. Hence
$e^{-x} = {1 \over e^x}$ and the desired result follows from $e^x > x$
for $x \ge 0$.